# How can I make a map editor?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a map editor. For 3 tiles I have to make 3 classes:

```
class cloud:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.image.load("top_left_outer.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(self.image.get_width()//4,self.image.get_height()//4))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.image,self.rect)

class clou:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.image.load("top_variation_02.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(self.image.get_width()//4,self.image.get_height()//4))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.image,self.rect)

class clo:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.image.load("top_right_outer.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(self.image.get_width()//4,self.image.get_height()//4))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

I want an easier way. How do I use my mouse to switch between tiles and place and save them?

```
clouds = []
clos = []
clay = []
platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
level = ["                                                                            ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                        c d     d     d  o          ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                            c d     d     d  o                                                ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                    c d     d     d  o                        ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "                                                                            ",
         "   c d     d     d     d     d     d     d     d     d     d     d     d     d  o",
         "                                                                        ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          ",
         "                                                                          "
         ]
for iy, row in enumerate(level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "c":
            new_platforms = cloud(ix*9.9, iy*45, 120,20,(23, 32, 42))
            clouds.append(new_platforms)

for iy, row in enumerate(level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "d":
            new_platforms = clou(ix*9.9, iy*45, 120,20,(23, 32, 42))
            clay.append(new_platforms)

for iy, row in enumerate(level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "o":
            new_platforms = clo(ix*9.9, iy*45, 120,20,(23, 32, 42))
            clos.append(new_platforms)
```

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/rXNfhVU3).

[image]

The code displays 1 image:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,700))
pygame.display.set_caption("Level Editor")


class cloud:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.image.load("top_left_outer.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(self.image.get_width()//4,self.image.get_height()//4))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.image,self.rect)


white = 155,155,155
cloud1 = cloud(200,200,50,50,white)
fps = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def redraw():
    cloud1.draw()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    redraw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Also see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Refactor my code" is far too broad, off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not fixed.  You added code that we can't run, and extended your request: we're supposed to figure out how your code works and refactor it for you.  You haven't bothered to give an example of making too many classes -- your code has only one class.  Your explanation runs from one issue to another, rather than asking a single, focused question.

Comment: The post still isn't minimal, but I see the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to continue generalizing the tile properties.  You don't make a different class for each position, size, and color; why do it for the image?  Just make that another instance parameter:

```
class cloud:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, color, image):
        ...
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        ...

cloud_list = {
    "top-left"  : cloud(200, 200, 50,  50, white,  "top_left_outer.png"),
    "top-right" : cloud(400, 200, 50,  50, yellow, "top_rght_outer.png"),
    "var2"      : cloud(300, 300, 50, 100, purple, "top_variation_02.png"),
    ...
}
```

This gives you a dict of tiles, indexed by a readable name.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: how would I call my dict list?  when I am enumerating it to create more tiles and also I am not sure how that would make it easier for me to place  more tiles TypeError: __init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What is a "dict list"?  I didn't discuss any list in my answer.  What do you mean about "call"ing it?  You don't "call" a data structure.  The error you give makes no sense without the code that causes it -- which would be a new question -- and it doesn't apply to the suggestion I posted.